# Array Adapter doesn't update

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, rx-java, retrofit2

I've this ArrayAdapter:

```
public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>  implements Filterable{

List<String> resultList;
private OnAutoCompleteListener listener;

private Context mContext;
private int mResource;


public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<String>resultList, OnAutoCompleteListener listener) {
    super(context, resource);

    mContext = context;
    mResource = resource;
    this.resultList = resultList;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Last item will be the footer
    return resultList.size();
}
public void updateList(List<String>values ){
    this.resultList = values;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return resultList.get(position);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) {
                List<String> resultList = listener.onAutoComplete(constraint.toString());

                Log.d(getClass().getName(),String.valueOf(resultList.size()));
                filterResults.values = resultList;
                filterResults.count = resultList.size();
            }

            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };

    return filter;
}
}
```

that gives results from this Flowable:

```
    void addToList(Places places){
    places.getPredictions().stream().forEach(s->System.out.println(s.getDescription()));

    places.getPredictions()
            .stream()
            .map(s->resultList.add(s.getDescription()));
}

@Override
public List<String> loadPlaces(String input) {

    HappyParkApp.getInstance().createAppComponent().inject(this);

    PlaceAPIService service = retrofit.create(PlaceAPIService.class);

    Flowable<Places> places = service.getPlaces(Constants.APIKEY,Constants.TYPES,Constants.LANGUAGE,Constants.COMPONENTS,input);

    places.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(newPlace -> addToList(newPlace));

    return resultList;
}
}
```

and this is the service:

```
public interface PlaceAPIService {

@GET("json")
Flowable<Places> getPlaces(@Query("key")String API,
                             @Query("types")String address,
                             @Query("language")String language,
                             @Query("components")String component,
                             @Query("input") String input);
```

}

it is correct and I could see a log to know if the service is good.
The problem is that the log that shows the item in the adapter is always 0.
Why?
Where I could update the adapter?

Thanks

**EDIT:** this are model, view and presenter:

```
public class APIModel implements AddWithText.Model {

@Inject
Retrofit retrofit;

AddWithText.Presenter presenter;

public APIModel(AddWithText.Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
}

final List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

void addToList(Places places){
    places.getPredictions().stream().forEach(s->System.out.println(s.getDescription()));

    places.getPredictions()
            .stream()
            .map(s->resultList.add(s.getDescription()));
}

@Override
public List<String> loadPlaces(String input) {

    HappyParkApp.getInstance().createAppComponent().inject(this);

    PlaceAPIService service = retrofit.create(PlaceAPIService.class);

    Flowable<Places> places = service.getPlaces(Constants.APIKEY,Constants.TYPES,Constants.LANGUAGE,Constants.COMPONENTS,input);

    places.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(newPlace -> addToList(newPlace));

    return resultList;
}
```

}

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_with_text, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this,rootView);
    HappyParkApp.getInstance().createAppComponent().inject(this);

    presenter = new AddWithTextPresenter();

    adapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item,autoComplete,this);
    DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final DatabaseReference condition = root.child("condition");

  insertText.setAdapter(adapter);


return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    presenter.setView(this);
}

@Override
public List<String> onAutoComplete(String character) {
    List<String> result = presenter.onTextChanged(character);
    return result;
}

@Override
public void refreshList(List<String> resultList) {
    adapter.updateList(resultList);
}

public class AddWithTextPresenter implements AddWithText.Presenter {


AddWithText.View view;
AddWithText.Model model;


@Inject
public AddWithTextPresenter(){
    model = new APIModel(this);
}

@Override
public void onComplete(List<String> resultList) {
  view.refreshList(resultList);
}

@Override
public void setView(AddWithText.View view) {
    this.view = view;
}

@Override
public List<String> onTextChanged(String character) {
    return model.loadPlaces(character);

}
```

}

Comment: Add code where you are setting adapter to list.

Comment: @androidnoobdev edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong here

```
adapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item,autoComplete,this);
```

in Adapter you have 4 parameters and you are passing only 3.

Second Check you are getting data here -

```
@Override
public List<String> onAutoComplete(String character) {
    List<String> result = presenter.onTextChanged(character);
    return result;
}
```

if so then your not passing data to adapter any where. add method like setData() in adapter and then pass data list to it. add following methods

```
public List<String> getData() {
    return resultList;
}

public void setData(List<String> mData) {
    this.resultList = mData;
}

public void addItems(List<String> mData) {

    if (this.resultList != null) {
        this.resultList.addAll(mData);
        notifyItemInserted(this.resultList.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but unfortunately does not work..I think that the problem is that in rx call arrives later than the call of the adapter..is there a good way to solve it?

Comment: Yeah there are so many ways with Rx. I haven't used Rx in any project but i know it has some method when it ends data sending to subscriber. you can check that method and then set adapter to list.